# Explanation for syntax

Tags: java, formatting, format, abstract-class, number-formatting

I'm learning java, can somebody explain me theory behind how the below syntax works? Below code prints value of payment in US currency format, but I would like to understand how initialized object and variables actually works. What does format method do here? Is it format method actually formatting variable or getCurrencyInstance?

```
NumberFormat us = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US);
System.out.println("US: " + us.format(payment));
```

Comment: Have you looked up the documention for the methods?

Comment: What exactly are you confused about? Are you unsure about the `NumberFormat` class itself?

Comment: The question isn't clear - please see [ask].

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `us` is a variable of type (class) `NumberFormat`.
- `getCurrencyInstance()` is a static method (a method of the class, not of an object). So this method is not related to a object. But this method generates an object of class `NumberFormat` (a kind of factory), that is stored in the variable `us`.
- now that you have a `NumberFormat` object, you can use it to format the `payment` as a string (following certain rules defined in your `us` object)